# Is there a way to identify the elements having 3 classes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I'm stuck in a case where the element is having 3 classes and I need to get the attribute value named "data-source" and should get the value.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls, share HTML elements here?

Comment: Please provide your HTML Dom code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get the *value* of the attribute `data-source` of the element having 3 classes e.g. `classA`, `classB` and `classC` you can use you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".classA.clasB.classC")).getAttribute("data-source"));
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='classA classB classC']").get_attribute("data-source"))
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)[Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [java](/questions/tagged/java) and *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".classA.clasB.classC"))).getAttribute("data-source"));
  ```
- Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and *xpath*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='classA classB classC']"))).get_attribute("data-source"))
  ```
- **Note** : For *Python* you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi Debanjan, Thanks for the quick reply but while using this in python it is throwing me only None values

Comment: @Sunny Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.